# How using enter event javascript in inputbox with multiple form

Tags: javascript, jquery

How using enter event javascript in inputbox if like this

this my code, i use the onclick but not work, how to use this if using enter event

```
<form id="msg_1" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" onclick="submit_msg("1")" name="post_msg_1">
</form>
<form id="msg_2" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" onclick="submit_msg('2')" name="post_msg_2">
</form>
<form id="msg_3" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" onclick="submit_msg("3")" name="post_msg_3">
</form>
```

and this my javascript

```
function submit_msg(uid) {
var msg= $("#post_msg_"+uid).val();
var dataString = 'msg='+ msg;
if (msg == '') {
alert("Insertion Failed Some Fields are Blank....!!");
return false;
} else {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://localhost/home/sendcmnt/"+uid,
data: dataString,
cache: true,
success: function(html){
$('#msg_'+uid)[0].reset(); // To reset form fields
}
});
}
return false;
}
```

how use the inputbox and javascript with enter?

thankyou

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please elaborate on what the problem is and what your question is.

Comment: @j08691 i dont how create good question but the problem is "How using enter event javascript in inputbox with multiple form"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this approach?

- First you text some value and push enter key on input field.
- After that form will send form data with Ajax.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sguugnft/1/)

HTML

```
<form id="msg_1" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" data-uid="1" name="post_msg">
</form>
<form id="msg_2" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" data-uid="2" name="post_msg">
</form>
<form id="msg_3" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" data-uid="3" name="post_msg">
</form>
```

and JavaScript

```
  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    var $form = $(this);
    var $post_msg = $form.find('[name="post_msg"]');
    var msg = $post_msg.val();
    var uid = $post_msg.attr('data-uid');
    var dataString = 'msg='+ msg;
    if (msg === '') {
      alert("Insertion Failed Some Fields are Blank....!!");
      return false;
    } else {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/home/sendcmnt/"+uid,
        data: dataString,
        cache: true,
        success: function(html){
          $form[0].reset(); // To reset form fields
        }
      });
    }
    return false;
  });
```